# Re-arrange columns after Unpivot ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, unpivot

If i start off with:

```
SELECT * FROM unpivot_test;

         ID CUSTOMER_ID PRODUCT_CODE_A PRODUCT_CODE_B PRODUCT_CODE_C PRODUCT_CODE_D
 ---------- ----------- -------------- -------------- -------------- --------------
     1         101             10             20             30
     2         102             40                            50
     3         103             60             70             80             90
     4         104            100
```

and when i Unpivot i get the values

```
SELECT *
FROM   unpivot_test
UNPIVOT (quantity FOR product_code IN (product_code_a AS 'A', product_code_b AS 'B', product_code_c AS 'C', product_code_d AS 'D'));

        ID CUSTOMER_ID  P   QUANTITY
---------- ----------- --- ----------
     1         101     A         10
     1         101     B         20
     1         101     C         30
     2         102     A         40
     2         102     C         50
     3         103     A         60
     3         103     B         70
     3         103     C         80
     3         103     D         90
     4         104     A        100
```

What if i want to make it so that quantity column shows BEFORE the P column, how would i go about doing this, i basically want

```
        ID CUSTOMER_ID   QUANTITY    P
---------- ----------- -----------  ----------
     1         101     10           A
     1         101     20           B
```

.....

oracle version is 11g

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT ID, CUSTOMER_ID, QUANTITY, P FROM
(SELECT *
FROM   unpivot_test
UNPIVOT (quantity FOR product_code IN (product_code_a AS 'A', product_code_b AS 'B',  
product_code_c AS 'C', product_code_d AS 'D')));
```

Comment: LOOOOOOOOOOOL WOWWWWWWWWWWWWWW OMGGG IM SUCH AN IDIOT